# How we can add icons & options in header bar ?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using simple blank header on my webpage. How I add icon inside header in right side alignment as like mention in image? I read all threads on StackOverflow but all was not useful, please provide a simple SCRIPT to I do this responsive.. thank you!

```
#header_container {
background: #232F3E ;
color:#fff;
border:1px solid #232F3E;
height:auto;
left:0;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
top:0;
}

#header {
height:42px;
line-height:42px;
margin:0 auto;
width:auto;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
}
```

[Header Icon Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s20iQ.jpg)

Comment: could you post the HTML for this?

Comment: Try an icon toolkit like https://fontawesome.com/

Comment: Not view in correct format.. https://ibb.co/bwVmB7

<!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->

<div id="header_container">
  <div id="header"> 
    <!-- site: LOGO --> 
<img src="/logo.php" title="MyWeb Title" alt="Welcome" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- END: Sticky Header -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was it something like this that you are after?

using font awesome icons and flexbox to create a right aligned navigation bar

font awesome:
https://fontawesome.com/icons?from=io

flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```js
$('#navButton').click(function() {
  $('.subNav').slideToggle('slow', function() {});
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #5d80ba;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 50;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navigation li a {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: #334ba1;
}

.subNav {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #8f80ba;
  z-index: 40;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.subNav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;

}

.subNav li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="navigation">
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-bed"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-beer"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-bed"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-beer"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="navButton"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
  </li>

</ul>

<ul class="subNav">
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-bed"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-beer"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-beer"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for pretty answer , but sir have a sometime visited sitepoint.com/community ? In mobile mode all options show in 2-3 but in desktop mode it become many, how? https://ibb.co/ePsKyn . How we add dropdown in fa fa icon link same as in image? Please help...

Comment: have a read of https://brolik.com/blog/responsive-web-design-menu-examples-css-jquery-tips/

Comment: I would consider using bootstraps https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Thank you for answer sir. It's great and working excelentes. I vote up. But could you help that when we browser on Mobile device show same to same this 3 buttons ibb.co/ePsKyn. And when it on desktop show like this https://ibb.co/jaG8b7.

Comment: For mobile look I am using ```@media screen and (max-width:420px)``` I am unable to add responsive logo which resign screen wish. Please help the dropdown of your code it open very slowly not (fast) or as like sitepoint.com/community also dropdown nit close when we click out of dropdown body. It must close when we click other point of body.and open fast. I am near my dream I don't known. Please help at last time.

Comment: I've given you a good starting point with links to lots of helpful information. I suggest you do some research, this site isn't for outsourcing people to write code for you, If you give it a go and still need help repost the new problem with your attempt as a new question.

Comment: Yes I know, and I am bit satisfied to your answer. But my issue is now that on ```@media screen and (max-width:420px)``` show 2-3 icon only or on desktop show full options. That's it. Please help answer with new updates . Please...

Comment: You are all genius.  What will decrease to post based by question answer. You are can do anything please help... I research too on Google or youtube but not get answer as my wish that's why I asking.